# numpy: int is a basestring?

Tags: python, numpy, types

How come `numpy` numeric types are subtypes of `basestring`?

```
for nptype in [np.int32, np.int64, np.integer, np.float]:
    for stype in [str, basestring, unicode]:
        print nptype, stype, np.issubdtype(nptype,stype)
<type 'numpy.int32'> <type 'str'> False
<type 'numpy.int32'> <type 'basestring'> True
<type 'numpy.int32'> <type 'unicode'> False
<type 'numpy.int64'> <type 'str'> False
<type 'numpy.int64'> <type 'basestring'> True
<type 'numpy.int64'> <type 'unicode'> False
<type 'numpy.integer'> <type 'str'> False
<type 'numpy.integer'> <type 'basestring'> True
<type 'numpy.integer'> <type 'unicode'> False
<type 'float'> <type 'str'> False
<type 'float'> <type 'basestring'> True
<type 'float'> <type 'unicode'> False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`basestring` isn't a dtype or sanely convertible to a dtype, and `issubdtype` doesn't have the error handling to recognize this. [It calls `numpy.dtype`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L728-L761) on `basestring` to get a dtype, and since `numpy.dtype` sees that the input is a Python type object it doesn't understand, the resulting dtype is the object dtype. The rest of the logic considers every dtype a subdtype of the object dtype.